# :hover state not working

Tags: html, css, hover, mousehover

I don't know why, but the `:hover` state is not working for the `.social` images. When I just isolate them and their class in a separate HTML file, they work. So something must be interfering in the rest of my code, I suppose.

Here's my HTML and CSS:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'></link>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<style>
.social{
border-radius:100%;box-shadow:0px 1px 0px white;height:30px;opacity:0.4;
}
.social:hover{
opacity:1;
}
</style>
<style>
.button{
font-size:17px;color:#c3c3c3;text-shadow:0px 1px 1px white;padding:13px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;border:1px solid #c3c3c3;border-radius:4px;box-shadow:0px 2px 7px -3px #c3c3c3;background: #eaeaea; background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eaeaea 0%, #dddddd 100%); background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#eaeaea), color-stop(100%,#dddddd)); background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eaeaea 0%,#dddddd 100%); background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eaeaea 0%,#dddddd 100%); background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eaeaea 0%,#dddddd 100%); background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eaeaea 0%,#dddddd 100%); filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eaeaea', endColorstr='#dddddd',GradientType=0 );
}
.button:hover{
box-shadow:0px 1px 1px white;
}
</style>
<div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;height:100%;width:100%;background: #f2f2f2; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #f2f2f2 0%, #cecece 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,#f2f2f2), color-stop(100%,#cecece)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #f2f2f2 0%,#cecece 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #f2f2f2 0%,#cecece 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #f2f2f2 0%,#cecece 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #f2f2f2 0%,#cecece 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f2f2f2', endColorstr='#cecece',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */">

<div style="position:absolute;right:25px;top:25px;">
<img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social/128/picons33.png" class="social">&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social/128/picons48.png" class="social">
</div>




<div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;">
<center>
<div style="width:900px;position:relative;height:100%;border:0px solid black;text-align:left;">
<img src="http://i46.tinypic.com/169i979.jpg" style="height:750px;position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:-350px;">


<div style="position:absolute;top:115px;right:0px;font-family:Lato;width:415px;">
<div style="font-size:75px;color:#f5f5f5;text-shadow:0px 2px 3px #c3c3c3;">dumbsearch.</div><span style="text-shadow:0px 1px 1px white;font-size:23px;color:#c3c3c3;">It's search like you've never seen or used.</span><br><span style="text-shadow:0px 1px 1px white;font-size:23px;color:#c3c3c3;">Scroll down to learn more.</span>

<br><br><br>

<span class="button">Apply to be a beta tester</span></div>
</div>


</div>
</center>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: Take out parts of the css at a time to see what's causing the issue. That code's a mess!

Comment: Why hove over them if you are not linking to anything or performing any action? Add a link to your social profiles then use a:hover.

Comment: @KeithDonegan I will have links. I just don't have any for now. I don't see why they're required for `:hover` to function.

Comment: They aren't, but makes no sense to make them hover using your current markup... You should really try and clean up your code.

Comment: @sachleen Yeah, my code formatting needs a lot of work. :P I don't even use a header most of a time (yeah I know, terrible!) And my use of inline stylesheets! brr...

Comment: You should work on that before asking for help on this issue, you may just find the problem yourself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the parent `div` of the two `.social` image elements, which is `position:absolute`, is been overlapped by its sibling `div`. By applying a positive `z-index` CSS style to it, the problem will be solved.

Comment: @DumbSearch By the way, I wouldn't consider using all these `position:absolute` stuff as a best practice. For this page, removing `position:absolute` style from `div`s other than the container of `.div` will not hurt anything (well, there might be an ugly white border, but it can be easily eliminated by applying `padding:none;margin:none;` to the `body`). :)